# Eclipse ADT plugin log out on linux

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, adt

Hi i have debian wheezy and installed eclipse and also the ADT plugin.
However, when i try to do "drag and drop" of some views to a layout, it logs me out of my session.
For example, if i try to drag and drop the "Person Name" view from the text fields, it logs me out, and the kdm screen appears. (i have KDE).
This seems really weird. I tried creating a new user but the problem is still there, thus it is not a user configuration conflict. 
Any ideas? Has anyone any similar problems?

**UPDATE**

As Marko suggested, i found some X logs and it seems that there is a segmentation fault.Here is the backtrace i get:

```
[ 15630.543] Backtrace:
[ 15630.543] 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x36) [0x7fedc274bc66]
[ 15630.544] 1: /usr/bin/X (0x7fedc25cd000+0x1827b9) [0x7fedc274f7b9]
[ 15630.544] 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7fedc18f5000+0xf030) [0x7fedc1904030]
[ 15630.544] 3: /usr/bin/X (miResolveColor+0x3) [0x7fedc2729dd3]
[ 15630.544] 4: /usr/bin/X (FakeAllocColor+0x62) [0x7fedc26121a2]
[ 15630.544] 5: /usr/bin/X (0x7fedc25cd000+0x16e3c3) [0x7fedc273b3c3]
[ 15630.544] 6: /usr/bin/X (0x7fedc25cd000+0x16fe4d) [0x7fedc273ce4d]
[ 15630.544] 7: /usr/bin/X (miPointerUpdateSprite+0x29a) [0x7fedc27372da]
[ 15630.544] 8: /usr/bin/X (0x7fedc25cd000+0x16a58d) [0x7fedc273758d]
[ 15630.544] 9: /usr/bin/X (0x7fedc25cd000+0xdb2f3) [0x7fedc26a82f3]
[ 15630.544] 10: /usr/bin/X (0x7fedc25cd000+0x10c7a7) [0x7fedc26d97a7]
[ 15630.544] 11: /usr/bin/X (0x7fedc25cd000+0x5a629) [0x7fedc2627629]
[ 15630.544] 12: /usr/bin/X (0x7fedc25cd000+0x62cc3) [0x7fedc262fcc3]
[ 15630.544] 13: /usr/bin/X (0x7fedc25cd000+0x5c503) [0x7fedc2629503]
[ 15630.544] 14: /usr/bin/X (ProcGrabPointer+0x140) [0x7fedc262c180]
[ 15630.544] 15: /usr/bin/X (0x7fedc25cd000+0x52e31) [0x7fedc261fe31]
[ 15630.544] 16: /usr/bin/X (0x7fedc25cd000+0x41ec5) [0x7fedc260eec5]
[ 15630.544] 17: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x7fedc061cead]
[ 15630.544] 18: /usr/bin/X (0x7fedc25cd000+0x4219d) [0x7fedc260f19d]
[ 15630.544] 
[ 15630.544] Segmentation fault at address 0x7fd5c358cdd6
[ 15630.544] 
Fatal server error:
[ 15630.544] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
```

---

As Marko suggested, i found some X logs and it seems that there is a segmentation fault.Here is the backtrace i get:

```
[ 15630.543] Backtrace:
[ 15630.543] 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x36) [0x7fedc274bc66]
[ 15630.544] 1: /usr/bin/X (0x7fedc25cd000+0x1827b9) [0x7fedc274f7b9]
[ 15630.544] 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7fedc18f5000+0xf030) [0x7fedc1904030]
[ 15630.544] 3: /usr/bin/X (miResolveColor+0x3) [0x7fedc2729dd3]
[ 15630.544] 4: /usr/bin/X (FakeAllocColor+0x62) [0x7fedc26121a2]
[ 15630.544] 5: /usr/bin/X (0x7fedc25cd000+0x16e3c3) [0x7fedc273b3c3]
[ 15630.544] 6: /usr/bin/X (0x7fedc25cd000+0x16fe4d) [0x7fedc273ce4d]
[ 15630.544] 7: /usr/bin/X (miPointerUpdateSprite+0x29a) [0x7fedc27372da]
[ 15630.544] 8: /usr/bin/X (0x7fedc25cd000+0x16a58d) [0x7fedc273758d]
[ 15630.544] 9: /usr/bin/X (0x7fedc25cd000+0xdb2f3) [0x7fedc26a82f3]
[ 15630.544] 10: /usr/bin/X (0x7fedc25cd000+0x10c7a7) [0x7fedc26d97a7]
[ 15630.544] 11: /usr/bin/X (0x7fedc25cd000+0x5a629) [0x7fedc2627629]
[ 15630.544] 12: /usr/bin/X (0x7fedc25cd000+0x62cc3) [0x7fedc262fcc3]
[ 15630.544] 13: /usr/bin/X (0x7fedc25cd000+0x5c503) [0x7fedc2629503]
[ 15630.544] 14: /usr/bin/X (ProcGrabPointer+0x140) [0x7fedc262c180]
[ 15630.544] 15: /usr/bin/X (0x7fedc25cd000+0x52e31) [0x7fedc261fe31]
[ 15630.544] 16: /usr/bin/X (0x7fedc25cd000+0x41ec5) [0x7fedc260eec5]
[ 15630.544] 17: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x7fedc061cead]
[ 15630.544] 18: /usr/bin/X (0x7fedc25cd000+0x4219d) [0x7fedc260f19d]
[ 15630.544] 
[ 15630.544] Segmentation fault at address 0x7fd5c358cdd6
[ 15630.544] 
Fatal server error:
[ 15630.544] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
```

Comment: For what it's worth, this should be Java related. Maybe try and install a different JVM.

Comment: i currently use openjdk 7. I will try oracle java 6 and i'll post results.

Comment: If it's killing the desktop session, it's unlikely to be a JVM issue -  either X or the whatever window manager you are running has just crashed.   Of course, it may be triggered by something that the ADT plug-in is sending it. Look in the logs for anything X-related.

Comment: True - no change when i use a different JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the ADT-bundle for Linux and see if the problem still remains!

Comment: I tried that and it's still the same. Tried ADT bundle, tried local eclipse install, tried general eclipse install.. can't think of something else to try:/

Comment: {workspace-folder}/.metadata/.log file and Window --> Show view --> General --> Error log check there and see if there are any error logs to provide us

Comment: Well there are just warnings that i exited without saving sessios, but that's all.